# Why my logitech blue-tooth keyboard and mouse don't work well with Mac

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

I bought a [Logitech](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NBMKAY8) wireless keyboard and mouse suite, but they do not work well with my Mac, the mouse usually gets stuck and the there is a large delay when typing with the blue-tooth keyboard. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Try changing 1) the batteries & 2) the relative positioning of the dongle & peripherals. Move away from all other electronics; speakers; TVs; fridge; microwave etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Logitec site does not specifically indicate [these devices are compatible](http://www.logitech.com/en-hk/product/mk240-nano-wireless-keyboard-mouse-combo) 
with Apple macOS.

These are the only compatible operating systems listed:

> Windows® 10 or later, Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Vista®, Windows XP,
>   Chrome OS™